# Insert Data in Acces DB using C# and Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, ms-access, parameters, insert

I try to insert some data in an Acces database using Parameters.AddWithValue 
but the result is that there is an error in the insert clause

```
private const string  conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data source= C:\Users\andres\" +
            @"Documents\synchro.accdb";
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new 
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(conString);
    OleDbCommand cmd;



public void setData(string temperature, string humidity,int month,int day,int year,string session)
    {

        //SQL STMT
    const string sql = "INSERT INTO termohigrometer(temperature,humidity,month,day,year,session) VALUES(@TEMPERATURE,@HUMIDITY,@MONTH,@DAY,@YEAR,@SESSION)";
       cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

        Console.Write("temperatura     "+temperature);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEMPERATURE", temperature);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HUMIDITY", humidity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONTH", month);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DAY", day);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR", year);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SESSION", session);

                   Console.Write("query  " +cmd.CommandText );
                try
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(@"Successfully Inserted");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

this is the result of the cmd.CommandText

```
INSERT INTO termohigrometer(temperature,humidity,month,day,year,session) 
VALUES(@TEMPERATURE,@HUMIDITY,@MONTH,@DAY,@YEAR,@SESSION)
```

This is the exception message

[image: This is the exception message]

Comment: Edit the question and show the exception details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These words *month,day,year,session* are reserved words for MS-Access. If you have fields with these names I strongly suggest you to change them to something different. Otherwise you need to put square brackets around them to avoid confusing the Jet Sql Engine.

```
const string sql = @"INSERT INTO termohigrometer
                  (temperature,humidity,[month],[day],[year],[session]) 
                  VALUES(@TEMPERATURE,@HUMIDITY,@MONTH,@DAY,@YEAR,@SESSION)";
```

Consider also to replace the AddWithValue method with the more precise Add method with a datatype for the parameter

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@TEMPERATURE", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = temperature;
 ....
```

Read this well known post about the dangers inside this 'convenient' method.
[Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: what a guy. able to spot the issue without exception msg. you deserve the upvote